# VB - No default member found for type 'DBNull' when inserting data into an array

Tags: sql, arrays, vb.net

I am trying to take data from a table and insert it into an array. However when I debug my code, Visual Studio returns this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.MissingMemberException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
>
> Additional information: No default member found for type 'DBNull'.

The procedure that runs and causes this error is as follows:

```
Sub characterChecked(ByVal pronunciation As String)
    Dim query As String = "SELECT Character FROM [Hiragana List] WHERE Pronunciation='" & pronunciation & "';" 'Selects the character from the SQL table
    Dim instruction = New SqlCommand(query, sqlCon)
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
    da.SelectCommand = instruction
    HiraganaList = New DataTable
    da.Fill(HiraganaList)
    dataArray(columnCount, rowCount) = HiraganaList.NewRow(0)("column") 'fills the first column in a row with the charater
    columnCount += 1 'Increments the coulmn count so that the pronunciation is in the same row as the character

    Dim query2 As String = "SELECT Pronunciation FROM [Hiragana List] WHERE Pronunciation='" & pronunciation & "';"
    Dim instruction2 = New SqlCommand(query, sqlCon)
    Dim da2 As New SqlDataAdapter
    da2.SelectCommand = instruction
    HiraganaList = New DataTable
    da2.Fill(HiraganaList)
    dataArray(columnCount, rowCount) = HiraganaList.NewRow(0)("row")
    rowCount += 1
```

And the debug breaks on this line:

```
dataArray(columnCount, rowCount) = HiraganaList.NewRow(0)("column") 'fills the first column in a row with the charater
```

The declarations for the array, the data table etc. are here:

```
Dim connectionString As String = "Server=my_server;Database=name_of_db;User Id=user_name;Password=my_password"
Dim sqlCon = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename='J:\Computing Coursework\real project\KES\KES\Kana List.mdf';Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30")
Dim HiraganaList As DataTable
Dim KanjiList As DataTable
Dim Katakana As DataTable
Dim YoonList As DataTable
Dim YoonKataList As DataTable
Dim columnCount As Integer = 1 'initialising the column and row counter for when data is inserted
Dim rowCount As Integer = 1
Dim varFileName As String = "J:\Computing Coursework\real project\KES\Resources\csv.txt"
Dim dataArray(1, 1) As String
```

If anyone could help spot the problem within my code, it would be very helpful. Personally, I think that the error is caused by not inserting data into the array in the correct way, however I don't know if what I am doing is incorrect or does actually work.

Comment: What is the purpose of the second query? You already know the value of 'pronunciation'

Comment: That is a very good point! Whoops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not really clear what you are trying to do, but the [NewRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.newrow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) call seems totally wrong. Not only it creates a new row initially empty but it seems that there is no overload that accepts a parameter.
So perhaps this is what you want to do.
(*Not testing about space available in the array to copy the value returned*)

```
Sub characterChecked(ByVal pronunciation As String)
    Dim query As String = "SELECT Character FROM [Hiragana List] WHERE Pronunciation=@pro"
    Dim instruction = New SqlCommand(query, sqlCon)
    instruction.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pro", pronunciation)
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(instruction)
    HiraganaList = New DataTable
    da.Fill(HiraganaList)
    if HiraganaList.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        dataArray(0, rowCount) = HiraganaList.Rows(0)("Character") 
        dataArray(1, rowCount) = pronunciation
    End If
End Sub
```

But at this point I am questioning if you really need it.
The `DataTable` is already a glorified array with many more functionality than a simple array.
So just calling

```
Function characterChecked(ByVal pronunciation As String) As DataTable
    Dim query As String = "SELECT Pronunciation, Character " & _ 
                          "FROM [Hiragana List] WHERE Pronunciation=@pro"
    Dim instruction = New SqlCommand(query, sqlCon)
    instruction.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pro", pronunciation)
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(instruction)
    HiraganaList = New DataTable
    da.Fill(HiraganaList)
    return HiraganaList
End Function
```

will give you a DataTable with many rows as returned by your query and two columns 
(`Pronunciation` at index 0 and `Character` at index 1)

```
Dim hira As DataTable = characterChecked(pronciation.Text)
Dim hiraChar = hira.Rows(0)("Character")
```

Comment: I need to take the data from that DataTable and several others, then put it into another datatable like object (so the array). Which can then have the data taken out of by calling something like an index or primary key. What syntax should I use to read data from the DataTable?